# Should SPF added to smtpd_sender_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions?

Tags: postfix

I am using postfix+dovecot in centos 7.
I use

```
postconf -e 'smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,reject_invalid_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_non_fqdn_recipient'
postconf -e 'smtpd_sender_restrictions =reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,check_policy_service unix:private/policy'
postconf -e 'policy_time_limit = 3600s'
postconf -e 'policy-spf_time_limit = 3600'
```

to set postfix main.cf.
Notice `check_policy_service unix:private/policy`in `smtpd_sender_restrictions`,which means I prove I am using right mail domain to send mail.
I think my `postconf`is perfect right, but somebody said `smtpd_sender_restrictions` should be in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.
Should SPF added to smtpd_sender_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options will function properly in either `smtpd_sender_restrictions` or `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

The reason that you should add them to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` has to do with the SMTP protocol itself. At each stage of the protocol, the sender first identifies itself with EHLO or HELO, then uses MAIL FROM to send the sender's email address, then RCPT TO to send the recipient's address. At each stage, Postfix can take action, e.g. with `smtpd_helo_restrictions`, `smtpd_sender_restrictions` and `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. But if you reject an incoming mail after the MAIL FROM, you do not know who the intended recipient is. If the mail was legitimate and the recipient complains, you cannot find them in the logs. By waiting until after the recipient address is sent, you can log all the available metadata about the message, in case you need to look it up later.

Comment: Is  `check_policy_service unix:private/policy` for `prove my email domain is true` or `check other domain is false`?

Comment: @kittygirl That runs the SPF check, which checks that the sender's domain is legitimate.

Comment: If you send mail to me,and you  domain has no SPF,can I receive your mail?

Comment: Yes, SPF is not required to send mail. SPF, if you use it, only tells others which IP addresses are authorized to send mail for your domain.

Comment: Suppose I use Thunderbird to receive your mail,any difference between `SPF true mail` and `SPF false mail`?

Comment: This is getting very far away from your original question. But Thunderbird does not check SPF records at all. Only the mail servers do this.

Comment: Set `TestOnly = 0` then I cannot receive `SPF fail mail`.